# onclick функция на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript

Хочу постепенно отказываться от использования jQuery.
Имеется блок с ссылками:

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<a href="/" current="">Публикации</a>
<a href="/?p=2">Проекты</a>
<a href="/?p=3">Отзывы</a>
<a href="/?p=4">Заказы</a>
</div>
<div class="right">
<a href="/?p=5">Чат</a>
<a href="/?p=6">Музыка</a>
<a href="/?p=7" current="">Оповещения</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Нужно что-бы при нажатии на ссылки в секции `class="left"` вызывалась такая функция: `ajax(this);`

Comment: `onclick="ajax(this)"` добавить к ссылкам?

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать именно как на js, ибо я стараюсь сократить все разделы кода, максимальную оптимизацию сделать.

Comment: А вот интересно, зачем отказываться от `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2):

Если ничего не путаю, то:

```
var someElements = document.querySelectorAll('.left a');

for (var i = 0; i < someElements.length; i++) {
    someElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        ajax(this);
    });
}
```

ES6

```
var someElements = document.querySelectorAll('.left a');

Array.from(someElements).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         ajax(this);
    });
});
```

`querySelectorAll` - выбирает все элементы по селектору

`addEventListener` - вешает слушателя на событие клика по элементу

Comment: Если es 6 то стрелочные функции должны быть везде...

Comment: function(event) {} На (event) => {}

Comment: ну и 'use strict' желательно

Comment: @Duoxx ES6 подразумевает стрелочные функции там, где нужно, а не бездумно совать везде

Comment: Есть отличия? Хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: @Duoxx ну зайди в любую песочницу, замени `ajax(this);` на `console.log(this);` и попробуй обаварианта. Отличия конечно есть. Они не просто тупо заменяют более длинную конструкцию

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите почему ссылка все равно срабатывает хотя я поставил в после ajax(this); - return false; ?

Comment: @user268403 вообще надо бы не в ajax, а именно в обработчик клика ставить. Но вообще лучше первой строкой напиши стандартное `event.preventDefault();`. Оно то уж работает........ А вообще я не вижу смысла делать ссылки, по которым нельзя перейти, проще делать стилизованные теги с атрибутом `data-*`. Тогда и проблем с ними не будет

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, с точки зрения SEO ты наверное неправ, что касается замены ссылок другим тегом (хотя могу ошибаться)

Comment: @MedvedevDev всё возможно. но пока грамотный сеошник мне этого не скажет и не покажет инфу, буду считать наоборот)

Comment: Ваш способ не подойдет, ибо поисковые системы не смогут путешествовать нормально, воспользовался вашим вариантом но он запрещает переход только на 1 раз, потом ссылка снова рабочая, интересно почему return false не работает...

Comment: @user268403 `но он запрещает переход только на 1 раз` - вранье!  https://jsfiddle.net/qk5yugn2/